# Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter login fails a few times before working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I've extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in spring-security 4.1.3 for logging into my website.  Here is my configure method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/index");
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/registerattempt", "/registeractivate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/images/**", "/favicon**", "/min/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

My form uses a thymeleaf action to post like this

```
<form id="loginform" role="form" th:action="@{/login}"
                      method="post">
```

I don't actually have a `POST` controller method mapped to `/login` in my code, just the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.  When I try to login it will just reload the login page the first 2 or 3 times I click the login button and the `/login` `POST` will have a 302 status code in the network log and there will also be a 200 GET for `/login`.  Then the 3rd or 4th time it will work and there will still be the 302 for the `/login` `POST` but it will `GET` my `index.html`.

This only happens when I am logging in for the first time in a while, if I log in and log out over and over the log in always works fine.  I'm using redis to store my session.  Why does it take several tries to login?

The only difference I see in the response header is

```
Location:http://localhost:8090/index
```

when it works and

```
Location:http://localhost:8090/login
```

when it doesn't work

**Update**
The debug logs are very verbose but I see this in the logs when it fails which isn't there when it works

```
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8090/login
```

Here's an excerpt when it fails

```
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8090/login
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1f8411e9
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.923 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
13 Jan 2017 20:20:58.931 [http-nio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

And when it works

```
13 Jan 2017 20:25:44.244 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
13 Jan 2017 20:25:44.244 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@3e3a840e. A new one will be created.
13 Jan 2017 20:25:44.244 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
13 Jan 2017 20:25:44.244 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
13 Jan 2017 20:25:44.244 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
```

Comment: I don't see anything different in the browser or server logs after making that change.  What should I be looking for?

Comment: try to remove your successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/index");

Comment: It still happens when I remove the successHandler object and use defaultSuccessUrl("/index") instead

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a login-processing-url to your http (HttpSecurity) instance:

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
```